# When making an object that interacts with things, is it better to have one big script or several different small scripts

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

Im working on a game inspired by Buckshot Roulette but medieval themed, in Buckshot Roulette the weapon can be picked up by the player, who can then point it at themselves or the "dealer", now im not sure if i should have all the interactions / actions of the weapon be in 1 big script or having several different scripts for each action.
The different actions / scripts need to be able to interact with eachother.

What would you all recommend i do?